# Usage of $n=∑_{d|n}Φ(d)$

Tags: number-theory, totient-function

Let Φ be Euler's totient function. Please tell me the usage of $n=∑_{d|n}Φ(d)$. Why is this formula important ?
One of the usage I found is to use this formula to derivate some another formula to calculate $∑_{i=1}^{n}Φ(i) $ in O($n^{2/3}\log{n})$ . Is there any other usage?

Comment: You may use such formula for proving that $\mathbb{Z}/(p\mathbb{Z})^*$ and $\mathbb{Z}/(p^k\mathbb{Z})^*$ (provided that $p$ is an *odd* prime) are cyclic groups, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has applications for arithmetic functions and the Dirichlet product $f\ast g$, in analytic number theory. Then the identity is equivalent to
$$
id=\epsilon\ast \phi,
$$
which implies that
$$
\phi=\epsilon^{-1}\ast id=\mu\ast id,
$$
which translates to
$$
\phi(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)\frac{n}{d},
$$
with the Moebius $\mu$-function.
This can be applied to zeta functions and results about prime number distribution. Another consequence is an identity by Selberg, which is the starting point for the so-called elementary proof of the Prime Number Theorem.

Comment: Very interesting formula.For me, $Φ(n)=\sum_{d|n}μ(d) \frac{n}{d}$ looks to calculate Φ(n) by the principle of inclusion-exclusion. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes; it is also called [Moebius-Inversion-formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula).

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is nice, isn't it? But it also appears in the proof of the claim that any finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of a field is cyclic...

You can check this in the first few pages of the wonderful little book "A Course in Arithmetic", by J.P. Serre